# PHP Get a specific property from an array of objects with different array count

Tags: php, arrays

I am in a confusing situation right now.

So, I have an array of objects

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▶]
  1 => array:2 [▶]
  2 => array:10 [▶]
]
```

Each array items contains another array which will have objects

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    0 => {#215 ▼
      +"DefaultTimeLength": 40
      +"ProgramID": 4
      +"NumDeducted": 1
      +"ID": 245
      +"Name": "30-Swedish-Massage"
    }
    1 => {#216 ▼
      +"DefaultTimeLength": 70
      +"ProgramID": 4
      +"NumDeducted": 1
      +"ID": 246
      +"Name": "60-Swedish-Massage"
    }
    2 => {#217 ▶}
    3 => {#218 ▶}
    4 => {#219 ▶}
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▶]
  2 => array:10 [▶]
]
```

What I want to achieve is, I want to get the 'ID' and 'Name' as an array for every array of objects from this array. Since, every array inside the main array have different counts, I cannot use a FOR loop, to get the required data. 
Any ideas?

Comment: _"I want to get the 'ID' and 'Name' for every array of objects from this array"_ -- get them how?  What's the expected output?

Comment: Get them as an array. array $id will have all the IDs, and $name array will have all the names

Comment: Since each group of objects you have in each array, seem to all have different ID's/Names, I'm not entirely sure how you expect the resulting output to be? Are you just displaying them all, or do you need to isolate "1" id/name for the entire array as your question is "I want to get the 'ID' and 'Name' for every array of objects"

Comment: @Randall I want to get the values as an array. $ids array will have all the IDs, and $name array will have all the names

Comment: Ok, so not trying to get a single ID/Name for a group... then the vague answer below about nested foreach will work for you. But it is vague on how it will work for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use nested foreach loop e.g:

```
foreach($main as $m){
   foreach($m as $item){
     echo $item->ID ." ".$item->Name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of an echo, how bout suggesting: `$ids[] = $item->ID; $names[] = $item->Name;`? (with proper initialization of course, and all that haha).

Comment: @Randall correct mate, but i am just telling him example how to loop through the array

Comment: Problem solved. Love you guys. I COMPLETELY forgot about the angel - foreach

Answer (score 0):

use 2 foreach loop inside eachother

```
    foreach ($array as $item) {
         foreach ($item as $sub) {
            echo $sub['ID'] . " " . $sub['Name'] . "<br>";
         }
     }
```

your full code will be something like [this](http://codepad.org/SkL1iMbO)